# Firebase serve does not produce same result as ng serve

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm new to web development and am trying to make a firebase hosted angular web app. I used angular-cli to generate this project from Webstorm.

I have a simple angular web app that displays text upon loading with

```
ng serve
```

and it's works fine: 
[working result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWSuW.jpg)

however, when I load the exact same code with

```
firebase serve
```

I get this:
[not working result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQG0B.jpg)

As far as I can tell there is some issue with firebase serve not connecting the component from `app.component.ts` to the html tag `<app-root>` in my code. Aside from that I have no idea what is going on and have spent a few days trying to figure it out.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </body>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.7/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "---",
      authDomain: "---",
      databaseURL: "---",
      storageBucket: "---",
      messagingSenderId: "---"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>

  <script>
    const myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['firebase']);
  </script>

</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {}
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>
   {{title}}
</h1>
```

**main.ts**

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment.prod';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase } from 'angularfire2';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [
  FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
  defaultFirebase('https://<NAME-OF-MY-APP>.firebaseio.com')
]);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';

// Initialize Firebase
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "---",
  authDomain: "---",
  databaseURL: "---",
  storageBucket: "---",
  messagingSenderId: "---"
}; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: did you run `Firebase init` on your project? https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart ?

Comment: Yeah, I've also got the firebase.json file with my public folder defined, etc. I can successfully deploy my app as well, however, it doesn't display as intended.

Comment: Ok cool, what error do you see in the developer tool bar after running `Firebase serve` ?

Comment: There aren't any errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out...

I've been deploying my src folder instead of the generated `dist` folder.

For anyone who doesn't realize they need to deploy their `dist` folder, run `ng build` to generate it. Then however you're deploying your site, upload the `dist` folder.

If using firebase to deploy, set your firebase.json `"hosting"` tag to:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist"
  }
}
```

then Firebase will always deploy your dist folder, just be sure to run `ng build` everytime you make a change and want to deploy that change.

If you're using WebStorm from Intellij and can't find your dist folder, in the `Project` tool window, switch to the "Project" option in the dropdown.

Comment: You can also run `ng build --watch` to get some of the live updating functionality, although I haven't yet found a way to live reload.